# Functional testing automation tools for iPad/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, testing, functional-testing, automated-tests

There doesn't seem to be many choices out there for running functional tests on the iPad/iPhone.  A quick search brought up a few options: FoneMonkey, Frank, UI Automation.

Does anyone have experience with any of these or have suggestions for better solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the [FoneMonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey) project founder, so admittedly a bit biased, but I would strongly recommend you give FoneMonkey a try. It provides robust recording and playback for native iPhone and iPad apps, and you can easily extend custom scripts with Objective-C logic to automate virtually any UI scenario.

The next release (due out later this week) generates UIAutomation-based tests in JavaScript, as well as ready-to-run OCunit tests.

Stu Stern

Answer (score 3):

I also found these:

UISpec: http://code.google.com/p/uispec/

Squish: http://www.froglogic.com/products/editions.php

Are there some more?

Answer (score 2):

This is another tool that could be used for UI testing.

Debugging with console environment.

libcat : interactive iPhone application development

https://github.com/wookay/libcat

Answer (score 0):

There is also one more app in app store. Name of app is TestStudio from Telerik. (http://www.telerik.com/)

It is good but you require Mac Book to install their extension where you can register your app and then use that app on iPad to test.

Hope this will help.